# link error while compiling this "simple" program with clang and g++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, constexpr, clang++

I am working on a project, and it seems that clang is unable to generate a valid bytecode (as the linker fail to link, some `static constexpr` in a template class is not found at link time)
I can fix it with a static getter in the class, but this lead to some really ugly/overloaded code.

Here is a "minimal" sample of code that makes the *bug* (is it a bug ?) appear.
Unfortunately, here, g++ will produce the same link error.

I'm asking if this is a compiler bug, or I am simply doing something wrong, and if there's a solution to avoid this error.
(And if I am doing something wrong, *why* the *same* construct works in my bigger project ??)

***NOTE**: The bigger project is named `yaggler` on github, but is still at the early beginning of its life*

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// exemple vector classes
struct vector2
{
  constexpr vector2(unsigned int _x = 0, unsigned int _y = 0) : x(_x), y(_y) {} // for clang

  unsigned int x;
  unsigned int y;
};
struct vector3 : public vector2 // uh ;)
{
  constexpr vector3(unsigned int _x = 0, unsigned int _y = 0, unsigned int _z = 0) : vector2(_x, _y), z(_z) {} // for clang
  unsigned int z;
};

// simple templated generic vector type
// we could make a more generic one, but this would require something like a tuple.
template<unsigned int... Vals>
struct vector
{
    static_assert(!(sizeof...(Vals) + 1), "[...]");
};
template<unsigned int X>
struct vector<X>
{
  using vec_type = unsigned int;
  static constexpr unsigned int value = X;
};
template<unsigned int X, unsigned int Y>
struct vector<X, Y>
{
  using vec_type = vector2;
  static constexpr vector2 value = vector2(X, Y);
};
template<unsigned int X, unsigned int Y, unsigned int Z>
struct vector<X, Y, Z>
{
  using vec_type = vector3;
  static constexpr vector3 value = vector3(X, Y, Z);
};

// a simple wrapper
template<typename V>
struct some_wrapper
{
  static constexpr typename V::vec_type value = V::value;
};

// a dummy function that print something to stdout.
void do_something(int32_t id, const vector3 &value)
{
  std::cout << id << " " << value.z << std::endl;
}
void do_something(int32_t id, const vector2 &value)
{
  std::cout << id << " " << value.y << std::endl;
}
void do_something(int32_t id, int value)
{
  std::cout << id << " " << value << std::endl;
}

// the class used to create the error
template< typename... Args>
class exemple
{
  private:
    // an initialisation that recurse over the Args... template arguments
    template<typename Current, typename... Others>
    void __rec_init() const
    {
      do_something(0, Current::value);
      __rec_init<Others...>();
    }

    // end of recursion
    template<size_t = 0>
    void __rec_init() const {}

    // launch the recursion
    void tpl_init() const
    {
      __rec_init<Args...>();
    }

  public:
    exemple()
    {
      tpl_init();
    }
};

int main()
{
  // and here, we get a linker error.
  exemple<some_wrapper<vector<4, 4, 5>>, some_wrapper<vector<4, 1>>, some_wrapper<vector<9>>>();
}
```

**EDIT**: just to mention gcc and clang versions: gcc 4.7.3/4.8.2 and clang 3.2/3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specializations of `vector` class template for 2 and 3 template arguments have got `static constexpr` data member `value` of literal type (`vector2` and `vector3`, respectively) that don't have namespace scope definitions.

You'll need them because you odr-use `value` when it binds to the reference parameter when passed to `do_something` function.

**§9.4.2/3 [class.static.mfct]**

> If a non-volatile `const static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class
>   deﬁnition can specify a `brace-or-equal-initializer` in which every `initializer-clause` that is an `assignment-
>   expression` is a constant expression (5.19). A `static` data member of literal type can be declared in the
>   class deﬁnition with the `constexpr` speciﬁer; if so, its declaration shall specify a `brace-or-equal-initializer`
>   in which every `initializer-clause` that is an `assignment-expression` is a constant expression. [Note: In both
>   these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. —end note ] **The member shall still be deﬁned
>   in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope deﬁnition shall not
>   contain an initializer.**

EDIT: Correcting myself, it's actualy `some_wrapper<T>::value` that needs this definition (for the reason mentioned above, nonetheless). So what you need is this in namespace scope after the definition of `some_wrapper`:

```
template<typename V>
constexpr typename V::vec_type some_wrapper<V>::value;
```

After that, your code [**compiles and runs**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5713511c14e79e32).

Comment: wow. I didn't think that I had to do this for `static constexpr` members. Thank a lot for the complete answer and the solution !!
(this effectively resolve the linker error in the _"bigger project"_)